# Audience targeting the navigation with SharePoint Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, audience-targeting, communication-site

I want to hide specific navigation links on a communication site for viewers but keep them visible for owner.
I stumbled upon audience targeting and the possibility to use SharePoint Groups.

I then created a group called **M365_Publisher** on the site but I can't select it in the target group box under the navigation link options.

Am I understanding target audience wrong or do I have to activate something else?

Comment: audience targets can only be Microsoft 365 groups or security groups. Additionally, the search box is not really handy, because you must write the group name correctly from the first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Groups are not supported for audience targeting in SharePoint online.

> Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) groups (including Security groups and Microsoft 365 groups) are supported.

**Source**: [Target navigation, news, and files to specific audiences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-and-files-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)

If you want Microsoft to allow using SharePoint groups, considering voting on below related UserVoice:

1. [Navigation audience targeting support SharePoint groups](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/40584448-navigation-audience-targeting-support-sharepoint-g)
2. [Allow using SharePoint groups to target audiences in quick links web part](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/42712238-allow-using-sharepoint-groups-to-target-audiences)

Comment: So how can I achieve the custom navigation? @Ganesh Sanap

Comment: You need to create Azure AD groups (either security or M365) to target audiences.