# Can we use SharePoint groups with target audience(top Menu) with Communication sites - SharePoint Online

Tags: publishing-site, communication-site, top-navigation

I'm looking to hide and show links on a SharePoint Communication site. So I enabled the Audience Targeting on the top menu.

But I discovered I could only use Microsoft 365 group or security groups in AD.

It doesn't work with SharePoint groups

Also I read some blogs that you can enable SharePoint Server Publishing infrastructure on Communication site but when I tried it I got an error. So its not enabled.

People also recommend using PNP but I read if you enable it on Communication site the top menu will disappear.

Does anyone know what would e the best solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You cannot enable publishing feature for communication sites. For communication sites, you will have to use M365 or Azure AD security groups only. Similar thread: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292377/audience-targeting-the-navigation-with-sharepoint-group/292378#292378

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to be aware that Azure Active Directory groups including security groups and Microsoft 365 groups are only supported in `Target Audiences` in **Modern** communication sites.

In **classic** experience sites, the Navigation links allow also SharePoint groups to be configured under audience targeting. If you have the `Publishing Feature` enabled. **BUT**, Classic publishing features are **NOT** available on modern communication sites.

**Ref:**

- [Target navigation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-files-links-and-web-parts-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)
- [Enable publishing features](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518#ID0EBBD=Classic)

**Workarounds**

- [Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on Modern](https://sharepoint-tricks.com/activate-sharepoint-server-publishing-infrastructure/)
- [Enable publishing features on Modern sites](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518#ID0EBBD=Classic)

Comment: Thanks Mohammed for your recommendations.
But Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on Modern doesn't work on Comms site.
Can you please confirm

Comment: You are welcome, as I mentioned in my answer, Classic publishing features are NOT available on modern communication sites.